# Azure Function in Python that is on a time trigger get zip file from a url, unzip, then output file to blob container in Azure storage

Tags: python, azure-functions

Here is my bindings in function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 30 7 * * *"
    },
   
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "jarvisetl/nppesraw",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my _init.py

```
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> str:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    zipurl = 'https://download.file.com'
    with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
        with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
            zfile.extractall(outputblob)
```

My biggest issue is I am getting an error that "outputblob" is declared in the function.json but not apparent in the python script. I am not sure where "outputblob" is truly suppose to go in the Python script.

Comment: The official document did not write, I wrote a simple example, you can look at my answer.

Comment: Hi, do you test my update answer?

Comment: I did but I got a new error with the connection string. The project has since been abandoned from azure function and done through Data Factory. I have a new question that builds on top of the work done in ADF.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142654/azure-data-factory-grab-file-from-folder-based-on-size

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest,outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    testdata = 'this is test.'
    outputblob.set(testdata)
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**Original Answer:**

Below is a simple example:

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "{test}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test1/{test}.txt",
      "connection": "str",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`init.py`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest,outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream],) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    testdata = 'this is test.'
    outputblob.set(testdata)
    name = req.params.get('name')
    return func.HttpResponse(f"This is output binding test, "+name)
```

Comment: params is not recognized by in my code. it is a timer triggered functon so there are differences as well

Comment: @DimejiOlayinka You just need to declare the binding first, and then put the data, that's all. This has nothing to do with what trigger you use. I use httptrigger as an example and hope you can understand this point. It has nothing to do with the type of trigger. Ok, since you say you are using timetrigger, I have update the answer. But the core idea is still to put data after declaring the data.