# Azure Data Factory grab file from folder based on size

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I ran a copy activity that used a http linked service to pull a zip file from an online and then extract the zip to a folder with multiple files within an Azure blob storage container. What I want to do now is dynamically pull the largest file from that newly created folder and run it through a data flow transformation while also deleting the folder through ADF. I am trying with a Get metadata activity that outputs the child items of the folder. The output is then connected to a ForEach activity with '@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems.' being passed in the Items of the ForEach setting with an inner GetMetadata activity to get the file sizes. But it errors on retrieving the file size giving me this..

{
"errorCode": "3500",
"message": "Field 'size' failed with error: 'Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=System,'.",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Get Metadata2",
"details": []
}

Is it not possible to get the file sizes of a folder's child items?. I was following this documentation.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a83712ef-9a1a-4741-80b5-0e2ee8288ef5/get-child-items-size?forum=AzureDataFactory&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a data factory
2. Setup a scheduled trigger, or trigger it a different way if you know exactly when all the files are done extracting/loading.
3. Create a metadata activity that will return metadata on a specific folder.
4. Grab the largest file from blob based on the metadata.

Comment: But when I do metadata activity of the folder it does not offer information on the size of the files within the folder. I can only pull it by name and I want to pull it dynamically by size as the name will change.

Comment: yes, you most certainly can grab the size from metadata filter

Comment: I cannot without a ForEach activity and I have added that and adjusted my question because I am getting a specific error